# iOS 5 linker error

Tags: ios5, linker-errors

After editing some code I am getting 4 build errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Playlist", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PlayerViewController.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_Song", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in PlayerViewController.o
"_currentIndex", referenced from:
  -[PlayerViewController viewDidLoad] in PlayerViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any tips on how to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes Xcode forgets to add classes in its compile list.

Go to project settings - target - Build Phases - Compile Sources and check if all the needed files are there.